# Facebook login api for mobile return users' info from real database

Tags: php, android, ios, api, security

i have a facebook login api for mobile apps . After singing up with facebook login the users fill their information and the information saving to our database . Everythings is working . I need if user back to our app and sing in with the same facebook account the saved information  return . I have same ways for returnign the datas for example via facebook user_id attech with my database . But in this point the api have a system vulnerability.For example if somene send an user id with curl or postman my api will return the user information to the attacker .
I need a way saving security for example checking facebook access token (i need checking facebook access token returned to mobile apps like graph . i think this will help me for keeping security ).

Answer (score 0):

The matter has been solved some months ago, I wanted to add the answer here.

Facebook provided us with an API which we can use to check the returned token from facebook. If the facebook token is valid, I generate a token, saving it into my database. In the end I return my own token to the user.